# Use JQuery to change all element's css style in same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change all the `background-color` of all `div`s with the class `Liregion2`.
I just want to change the `div` background color, not `li`.
My code only changes one `div` element, though! How can I make it affect all of them?

Here is my HTML5 code:

```
<div class = "Liregion2" id = "LineBock1" style ="padding-bottom:3%;padding-left:10%;background-color:#ff9900"> 
 <li>
   <a href="#" id = "FirstLine" style="color:#fff;text-decoration: none" >1號線</a>
 </li>
</div>  
<div class = "Liregion2" id = "LineBock2" style ="padding-bottom:3%;padding-left:10%;">             
 <li>
   <a href="#" id = "SecondLine" style="color:#009999;text-decoration: none" >2號線</a>
 </li>
</div>  
<div class = "Liregion2" id = "LineBock3" style ="padding-bottom:3%;padding-left:10%;"> 
 <li>
   <a href="#" id = "ThirdLine" style="color:#ff3366;text-decoration: none" >3號線</a>
 </li>
</div>  
<div class = "Liregion2" id = "LineBock4" style = "padding-left:10%;">  
 <li>
  <a href="#" id = "ForthLine" style="color:#0066ff;text-decoration: none" >4號線</a>
 </li>
</div>
```

And here is the JQuery:

```
$('#FirstLine').click(function(){
    $('.Liregion2').each(function( index , element  ){
            $(element).css("background-color" , "transparent");
    });     
    event.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

Comment: Create a jsfiddle.net

Comment: `css` iterates through the collection behind the scenes, there is no need to use a `each` loop. Also your markup  is invalid, `li` should be child of an `ul`/`ol` element.

Comment: You are using inline css and inline css cann't be overridden,secondly you have problems in your markup you are using <li> inside div its not possible like this you would have to use it inside <ul> <li></li> </ul>.Kindly fix your issues.write css in seperate style sheet and then include it as a class or as a id selector rather than using inline styles.

Comment: @kimWong Provide jsfiddle.net link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`css` method iterates through the collection behind the scenes, there is no need to use a `each` loop. Also your markup is invalid, `li` element should be child of an `ul`/`ol` element. The `div` elements should be replaced with one of the above elements (*although it won't be a semantic markup*.)

It seems you only want to manipulate `css` properties of the parent element. If this is the case, you can use `.closest()` or `.parent()` method:

```
// Do not miss the `event` object if you want to use it
$('.Liregion2 a').click(function(event) { 
    $(this).closest('.Liregion2').css("background-color" , "transparent");
    event.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

As a suggestion avoid using inline styles, it makes the markup unmaintainable. You can declare CSS classes, and use jQuery `removeClass` and `addClass` methods for adding/removing them.

Comment: thank you, but can i use <ul><div><li></li></div></ul>?  is it legal?

Comment: @KimWong You are welcome. Unfortunately, that's invalid. Each browser will parse it differently. I'd suggest using just one `ul` element with those `li`s as it's children. Then you can put your `div` elements (_or whatever valid markup that is needed_) as the `li`'s descendants.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to loop through each element. try this,

```
$('#FirstLine').click(function(){
    $('.Liregion2').css("background-color" , "transparent");
    event.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

Comment: This is better than using `each` (_in this case_), but it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of that complicated code, the `.css()` function iterates through the elements by itself and applies CSSs to all the elements.

```
$('#FirstLine').click(function() {
    $('.Liregion2').css("background-color" , "transparent");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$(document).on("click", "#FirstLine", function(){      
    $('.Liregion2').css("background-color" , "transparent");    
});
```